# Rationale for a parenthesized ternary expression returning a function name in a function pointer declaration in C

Tags: c, function, pointers, function-pointers, conditional-operator

In K&R2 book, on page 119 in the section on function pointers, there is the following parameter declaration for a function pointer:

```
(int (*)(void*,void*))(numeric ? numcmp : strcmp)
```

`numcmp` and `strcmp` are function names, and `numeric` is a boolean variable that decides which of these two functions is pointed to by the function pointer that the expression declares.

I don't understand how and why this works. If I were attempting to write this expression, my attempt would be more like:

```
int (*(numeric ? numcmp : strcmp))(void*,void*)
```

The best way I can make sense of the K&R construction is that the first parenthesized part - `(int (*)(void*,void*))` - acts as a function, and the second - `(numeric ? numcmp : strcmp)` - acts as the function parameter, and the whole returns the function pointer declaration. But to think of it this way doesn't connect with anything I've learned about C.

I have read some excellent guides on how to understand complex pointer expressions in C. You basically "spiral out" from the innermost expression outward. But this one has me stumped, it doesn't conform. Could someone please explain?

Comment: related, you may want to check the errata of that page of the book. It literally apologizes for the questionable cast due to the different function pointer argument types, as well as abusing the name `qsort`, thus likely confusing people with the runtime library function of the same name, but considerably different parameters.

Comment: @WhozCraig Doh, I read that errata on first reading of the book and completely forgot about it. The expression isn't wrong though, so it is still good to note it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(int (*)(void*,void*))` is a normal *type-cast*.

If we create a type-alias

```
typedef (int (*function_type)(void*,void*));
```

it would perhaps be easier to understand when used:

```
(function_type) (numeric ? numcmp : strcmp)
```

In short, the ternary expression returns a pointer to a function, and then the result (the function-pointer) is cast to a specific type.

Comment: Thank you! If the ternary returns a pointer to a function, using the function names, then why cast to a pointer to a function? I guess it's needed to make the whole cast work.

Comment: Note that the use of the result without casting it back to the right function type is undefined behavior, and always has been in standard C. Presumably this code is pre-standardization or there's more context to make it work.

Comment: @Theod'Or To answer that we need more context. Is the pointer assigned to a variable? Also [`strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) doesn't take `void *` as arguments, which it seems the result need to do.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The context is simply that the expression is a function pointer declaration in a parameter list of a function. I've accepted your answer as it clearly is correct, as evidenced by the errata referred to in the comments to my question.

Comment: You called a pointer typedef `function_type` ... argh.  Function types and pointer types are different, I would suggest either calling it `function_pointer_type` , or actually using a function typedef

Answer (score 4):

The expression is from p119 of Brian W Kernighan and Dennis M Ritchie
[The C Programming Language, 2nd Edn](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/0131103628) (1988).

It is simply a cast of one of two function pointers (selected by the ternary expression) to a common type, `int (*)(void *, void *)` to match the signature of the variant of the `qsort()` function that is written on p120 of K&R2.

However, IMO, that piece of code officially runs foul of 'undefined behaviour' according to the C standard.

> C11 [§6.3 Conversions]
>
> [§6.3.2.3 Pointers ¶8](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p8)
>
> A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a function of another type and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer. If a converted pointer is used to call a function whose type is not compatible with the referenced type, the behavior is undefined.

You can check the requirements on compatible types in [§6.2.7 Compatible type and composite type](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.7) and [§6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes) ¶15](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.3p15).

The code referred to in the question is an invocation of a variant of the standard C [`qsort()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.5.2) function.  The standard function has the signature:

> ```
> void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
>            int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
> ```

In the code in the book, they are using their own, related function `qsort()` with the rather different signature:

> ```
> void qsort(void *lineptr[], int left, int right, int (*comp)(void *, void *));
> ```

Now, the code in the `qsort()` variant is going to invoke the function identified by `comp` with two `void *` values.  So, to avoid undefined behaviour, the function that is passed to `qsort()` as the comparator *should* have the signature:

```
int comparator(void *p1, void *p2);
```

Now, the code passes the comparator using:

```
(int (*)(void *, void *))(numeric ? numcmp : strcmp)
```

The `strcmp` function implementations on p106 do not quite match the standard C [`int strcmp(const char *, const char *)`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.4.2); it is their own minor variant of it missing the `const` qualifiers (`int strcmp(char *, char *)`). However, the code on p119 includes `<string.h>` so it probably is the standard version that is used.  The signature of `the`numcmp` function is given as:

```
int numcmp(char *, char *);
```

The cast in the call is legitimate — you can convert a function pointer from one type to another (and back again).  What is not legitimate — in the strictest interpretation — is that their variant of `qsort()` is going to invoke those functions as if their type was `int function(void *, void *)` and the standard says "that's undefined behaviour".

Additionally, [§6.5.15 Conditional operator](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.15) says that the two expressions on either side of the `:` must satisfy one of a series of 6 conditions, the relevant one of which is:

> - both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types;

Now, given that both the functions have the signature `int function(char *, char *)`, this is OK.  If the `strcmp()` was the standard C version, it is treading on thin ice because of the `const`-qualifiers.

Given that it is a custom `qsort()` and that the two comparators have the same signature, it would be reasonable to use this signature:

```
void qsort(void *lineptr[], int left, int right, int (*comp)(char *, char *));
```

Then it would not be necessary to coerce the types when `qsort()` is called — the function pointer argument would be simply:

```
(numeric ? numcmp : strcmp)
```

and the code in the `qsort()` wouldn't need to change because there's an automatic conversion in C from `void *` to any other type — `char *` in this case.

#### Summary

In practice, you will almost invariably get away with the code shown in K&R2.  But strictly, the code is invoking undefined behaviour because it is not casting the function pointers back to their original type(s).

If you are using the standard C `qsort()`, you should always pass a comparator that matches the signature:

```
int comparator(const void *p1, const void *p2);
```

You should not, therefore, need a cast on the function pointer in the call to `qsort()` because that signature will be used by `qsort()` to call your function.  Inside your comparator function, the code will convert the two `const void *` values into suitable (`const`) pointers of the correct type, and run the comparisons using those types.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed analysis, providing the context that Someprogrammerdude asked for in the comments to his answer. (I see on p120 of K&R2 that the cast is in fact explained, though I missed that point.) I'm confused by your claim that the way this is done in the book is not completely standard. If any function parameter type may be converted to `void *` and back again, then isn't such casting considered always compatible? That's what the first paragraph on p120 seems to suggest. Your C11 quote refers to function pointers, not function parameter pointers. Do I misunderstand something?

Comment: The problem is that inside the `qsort()` function, the expression `(*comp)(v1, v2)` invokes a function that has the signature `int function(void *, void *)`.  Unfortunately, neither `numcmp` nor `strcmp` has that signature (they have the signature `int function(char *, char *)`), and those two different signatures are not compatible.  Consequently, calling the functions with the 'wrong' pointer type is 'undefined behaviour', which means it may work as expected (and it probably will), or it may go haywire in any creative way that is deemed desirable by the compiler. _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ For example, it might decide "that's I nice disk drive; I'll format it for you since you gave me permission to do so" (search "nasal demons"). It probably won't, but it could. If the revised `qsort()` taking `int (*comp)(char *, char *)` as the comparator was used, the two `void *` values passed in the call `(*comp)(v1, v2)` would be converted to `char *` automatically because the function pointer says the arguments are of type `char *` and `void *` can be converted to `char *` (and it is  a no-op because [C11 §6.2.5 ¶25](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p28)).

Comment: I'm reluctant to criticize K&R for something that was pretty much normal at the time (30+ years ago), but what is considered good modern C has changed quite a bit over that timeframe.  There are other places where the book is a product of its time — for example, the outline implementation for reading directory data simply doesn't work on modern file systems (Unix or Windows).

Comment: Another problem (but definitely not "their fault") is that they show some versions of a function `getline()` that is now standard in POSIX ([`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html)) but which has a wholly different call interface and semantics. That's unfortunate; it confuses people using the code for exercises. (This `qsort()` is also problematric because it has a different interface from the standard C `qsort()` as noted in my answer and in comments to question. That was less excusable.) Don't get me wrong K&R2 is good, but it is old and it shows.